# How to call a route once in Fastapi and block calling it again (display a "process running" message) until execution completes

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, fastapi

There is a need to wait for a function to be executed and to protect it from being called again. It is necessary to protect the route call from being called again; if the route is called again while the process is not completed after the first call, display a message such as "task in process".

Tried to use BackgroundTasks but I can't track whether the task is running or has already completed execution.

Comment: Add a lock of some kind - if you need it to be distributed across workers/node, using any regular database, redis, memcached or another storage solution. You'll have to keep track of whether a task is running and then set it as terminated when finished. You can also use one of the many task queues with a single worker if you want to allow multiple tasks to be queued up.